# How can i redirect a following url to a path existing using nginx

Tags: nginx

Want to redirect https://mylocal.com to https://mylocal.com/public/build/index.html

where path of index.html is /opt/domain/subdomain/public/build/index.html

have tried

```
    location = / {
    return 301 /opt/domain/subdomain/public/build/index.html;

    }
```

It should redirect to /https://mylocal/public/build/index.html

Answer (score 0):

https://mylocal.com to /https://mylocal.com/public/build/index.html

```
location = /index.html {
  return 301 /public/build/index.html;
}
```